# yaml exception in google app server "unable to add testProject to attribute application" regex issue?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

first day with google app engine.

my yaml file includes the following:

```
application: testProgram
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

my python file includes the following (just for giggles):

```
import webapp2


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.reponse.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write("Hurray for cake!")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],debug=True)
```

the error I am getting is the following:

```
ile "/home/rickus/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 178, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unable to assign value 'testProgram' to attribute 'application':
Value 'testProgram' for application does not match expression '^(?:(?:[a-z\d\-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!\-)[a-z\d\-\.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,99}[a-z\d])$'
  in "testProgram/app.yaml", line 1, column 14
```

so it is complaining about the naming of my file? That  can't be right? I any ideas?

Comment: Of course it can be right it is complaining about your program name, it cannot contain uppercase characters (probably to prevent these unreadable camelCase words)

Comment: @Anthon it most certainly can be, I'm just flabergasted. I didn't even realize that was the problem I camelCase everything, I don't even think about it. Lame.

Comment: I don't know if there is an additional explanation, but since the software processing your YAML file is in Python (deducted from the format of the error message), it seems the programmers applied the "rules" from Python (ie. use `under_scored_multi_word_names`). It could of course be that the underlying filesystem where your app is store is case-insensitive ...

Comment: @Anthon The reason for using lowercased alphabets is that you can push your code to <app-id>.appspot.com and run it on google's servers. Since urls are not case sensitive, it makes perfect sense to allow only a-z separated by '-'s

Comment: @shravster Thanks for the explanation. I assume you meant to write that **domain names** are not case sensitive, URLs most certainly can be case sensitive.

Comment: @Anthon, that's right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely complaining about your applicationId, look at the regex, it accepts lowercased chars only.

Change your applicationId to "testprogram" or "test-program"

Comment: ugh Ive spent so much time for such a silly thing. Thank you. Hugs and kisses. I'll accept and upvote your answer